# How to compile C++ mongo project

Tags: c++, mongodb, gcc

I need help! How to compile c++ mongo project in linux?

I'm doing this:
 1) Install boost
 2) Compile mongodb driver
 3) Try to compile example (fail)

My compile mongodb drivers exist in /home/developer/documents/drivers/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.4/build

I'm trying to compile this file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

void run() {
  mongo::DBClientConnection c;
  c.connect("localhost");
}

int main() {
  try {
    run();
    std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
  } catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
    std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And execute this command: g++ tutorial.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -o tutorial

This command fail. Error message - "mongo/client/dbclient.h" not found. How to compile this example? Help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use -I and -L to specify where you have installed your mongo header(s) and library(ies):

```
g++ tutorial.cpp -I/path/to/mongo/include/ -pthread -L/path/to/libmongoclient 
                 -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options 
                 -lboost_system -o tutorial
```